# Preparation for moving to Prague: what comes first?

Tags: working-visas, eu-citizens, paperwork, working, czech-republic

I'm an 18 year old software developer from The Netherlands interested in moving to Prague. 
I'm wondering in which order I should go about moving to Prague in terms of getting visas, work permits, renting a apartment, getting health insurance, finding a job and other stuff. At this moment I'm confused in what order I should start arranging things.

Thank you in advance if anyone can help me clarify!

Comment: As a Dutch citizen, [you won't need a visa or a work permit to travel to and work in Czech Republic](http://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=457&langId=en), since both countries are part of EU. I don't think the other items depend on each other, so there is no fixed order to arrange them in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend to start by looking for a job. First, it will be less stressful to move into a new country if you already have a job lined up; second, your employer will probably be able to help you with all the paperwork.

If you're a Dutch citizen, you won't need a visa or a work permit (as @svick points out in their comment). You need health insurance from the first day living in the Czech Republic (unless you're on social benefits, for which you're not eligible) so that's another reason to find a paying job first. Getting an apartment can prove difficult if you don't have a steady income.